# Unity inactive object destroyed

Tags: unity-game-engine

So after my player hits 0 HP, the player object (in my case a rocket ship) is set to false and the Game Over UI is set to true. Then the player has two options: either to restart or resume the game. Only resuming the game plays an ad, but after the ad is done playing the game doesn't continue and I get the error saying "The object of type 'GameObject'(The Game Over UI) has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it". Now I know that this happens when I specifically destroy an object, but not when I set the object to inactive.

Game Over function

```
    private void GameOver()
    {
        Time.timeScale = 0f;
        GameOverUI.SetActive(true);
        finalScore.text = score.ToString() + " Meters";
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("Score", 0);
        totalCash.text = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("Cash", 0).ToString() + " Cash";
        highScoreTracker.text = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("HighScore", 0).ToString() + " Meters";
    }
```

Resume function called from Ads Manager after ad is played

```
    public void ResumeGame()
    {
        GameOverUI.SetActive(false);
        this.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("Score", score);
        Time.timeScale = 1.0f;
    }
```

Ads Manager function

```
    public void OnUnityAdsDidFinish(string placementId, ShowResult showResult)
    {
        if (activeScene == "InitialEarth" || activeScene == "Earth" || activeScene == "Space" && showResult == ShowResult.Finished)
        {
            player.ResumeGame();
            timesWatched++;
            if (timesWatched >= 2)
            {
                adButton.interactable = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

The error is pointing to the lines "GameOverUI.SetActive(false)" and "player.ResumeGame()".
I've tried keeping the player object active when its game over but same error. I have a similar function, like my Pause UI, where it's inactive initially and with a button click, its set to active and then inactive again and that works fine.

I'm not sure what's wrong or where to look. Is there another way to deactivate and active object? Why would an inactive object give a destroyed error, since its still in the game hierarchy? Any help or pointers would be much appreciated. If more info is needed, please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Is it the player class the one calling the ResumeGame() method?. Maybe the player is the one that is destroyed. Would make sense player is destroyed when the game is over, not to call the resume game from the player though ;)

Comment: @rustyBucketBay Yes, so does this mean that when an object is set to inactive, it is treated as being destroyed? I'll set the player to active before calling the ResumeGame() method and see how that works.

Comment: inactive gameobject should not give a destroyed error. You must be destroying GameOverUI somewhere in your code

Comment: What I'm confused with is that the object is still on screen when I get that error. I removed the ads part and just had the game resume without the ad playing, and it works. So the ads manager is destroying the GameOverUI somewhere.

Comment: that seems to be the case. Check all the references to the GamoOverUI (alt + f12) and there you can check al the places where GameOverUI is manipulated in the code. There you can find where it might be being destroyed

Comment: @rustyBucketBay I've done more exploring and I believe the GameOverUI gets destroyed during scene changes. I have three scenes: player starts in Scene 1, after a certain score goes to Scene 2 and then again to Scene 3. The Resume works when its in one scene, but when it enters another scene, the first time it hits the GameOver, I get the object destroyed error. I've put DontDestroyOnLoad at the Start methods of both the Player and AdsManager scripts, but those haven't fixed the issue.

Comment: there you got it. I dont know what you mean by putting dont destroy on load at the start. You need to follow the docs to avoid the object destruction when scenes are loaded: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html